# What is the scope of "exported" in Unix shell variables?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, environment-variables

I have set some environment variables in the following way:

```
MY_VAR='helloworld'
export MY_VAR
```

Then I have switched to another user via

```
su SOME_OTHER_USER
```

I echo the MY_VAR variable.. and I see its value!

1) Could you please explain this issue. As far as I understand when I export variable via export command it is not a "global" export, its just a user-local variable. Why I see it?

2) Initially I had a guess: may be, when I switch to another user I start some child process of my bash process, and thats why I can see my variable because the exported vars are passed to any child process of current shell. But command `ps ---pid <my bash's pid which I got with echo $$>` shows only the same pid in output. So looks like this means there are no child processes related to my bash process and su is not starting any process. Am I right?
(by the way, I dont see a single 'child' this way, even if I start another bash with bash command, I dont know why)

3) Finally, who can see the variable I have exported that way? Given I start some other process from my OS GUI - am I about to see it? Looks like no, because if I start another terminal I dont see it there. So what is the scope and lifetime of my exported variable?

I use Debian Wheezy. I was running my command from RootTerminal under Root user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- OK, for starters, I think you mean `ps --pid` and not `ps ---pid`.
- You don't need to `echo $$` 
  and then type the number into `ps --pid number`;
  it's good enough to type `ps --pid $$`.  Unless you're talking about

  ```
  # echo $$
  42
  # su joe
  % ps --pid 42
  ```

  in which case you're doing the right thing.
- What were you expecting?

  > **--pid** *pidlist*
  >
  >   Select by process ID.  Identical to
  >   **-p**
  >   and
  >   **p**
  >   .
  >
  > **-p** *pidlist*
  >
  >   Select by PID. 
  >     This selects the processes whose process ID numbers appear in
  >   *pidlist*
  >   . 
  >     Identical to
  >   **p**
  >   and
  >   **--pid**
  >   .

  So, when you do `ps --pid PID_of_shell`,
  you're getting the line of `ps`'s output *for the shell process only*. 
  You might find `ps -l | grep PID_of_shell` more useful;
  it will show any line that contains *`PID_of_shell`* anywhere,
  including in the PPID column. 
  I.e., it will show child processes of the shell. 
  But, of course, `grep 42` will find things like `7428`.
- Your guess is right; environment variables are passed from parent to child. 
  As indicated above, your **`su`** shell is a child of your login shell
  (or other parent shell). 
  Note, however, that a process can change its environment;
  `sudo` is somewhat notorious for doing this,
  and `su` does it too (e.g., it changes `$USER`, `$LOGNAME`, and `$HOME`
  unless you specify `--preserve-environment`,
  and even more if you do specify `--login`). 
  Also, a process can pass its children a different environment
  than the one it is using; the shell does that when you say something like
  `PAGER=cat  man  man_page_topic`. 
  References: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23396/23408), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189382/23408).
- So, no, if you set (export) an environment variable in the shell
  in one terminal, and then start another terminal through the window manager,
  it will not see the environment variable, because it is not a child
  (or descendent) of the shell that set it. 
  But, if you start a new terminal window *from the shell* (e.g., by `xterm&`),
  then that terminal window will inherit the shell's environment.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, Scott! Still cannot get one thing: given I issue ps -l and I see: 0 S     0 26083  4862  0  80   0 -  4918 -      pts/3    00:00:00 bash; then I go su SOME_USER and see 4 S   116 26780 26772  0  80   0 -  4850 -      pts/3    00:00:00 bash. There are no 26083 PID of my main bash process! So how can I 'prove' that su creates a sub-process?

Comment: Got it: I just need ps -Al | grep 26083

Comment: Here's an exercise: type `ps -lp $$`. Note the number in the PPID column. Then do `ps -lp (that number)`. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to understand if you were accessing the machine with ssh, rlogin, or telnet, even as the same user.  (rlogin/telent are not recommended)

If you set and export a variable from tty1 as user foo, any child process can see the variable and its value.  But if you start a whole new session, ie. from tty2, as user foo, the variable will not be visible.

1) When you export a variable, you make it global (in session context).  As a side note, I strongly discourage the use of working in a "root" shell.  Mistakes and accidents are far less forgiving when executed by this user/account.

2) The su command is a set (or switch) user utility.  You are still in your original session.  This is why you can still see your exported variable.

3) The scope is the current session and the lifetime is the duration of that session (until you logout, assuming you do not reset or change the variable again).  If you spawn new xterms from the parent session, the children still see your exported variable.  If you start new sessions/terminals, variables and their values from the other tty(s) are not visible.